# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.gson.JsonElement.toString()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, android-studio

```
  private void getNewPhotos() {
        Call<JsonElement> call1 = RestClient.post().getNewPhotos(Config.NEW_ID, Config.unsplash_access_key);
        call1.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
                //  progressDialog.dismiss();
                newPhotoslist.clear();
                Log.e("FeatureNews", response.body().toString());
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    JSONArray jsonArr = null;


                    try {
                        jsonArr = new JSONArray(response.body().toString());
                        if (jsonArr.length() > 0) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject json2 = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
                                String id=json2.getString("id");

                                JSONObject object=json2.getJSONObject("urls");
                                String url=object.getString("regular");

                                JSONObject objectUser=json2.getJSONObject("user");
                                JSONObject objectUserProfile=objectUser.getJSONObject("profile_image");
                                String userprofile=objectUserProfile.getString("large");


                                newPhotoslist.add(new PhotosBean(id,url,userprofile));

                            }

                            bindTrendData();

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            }
```

Comment: Seriously? The error captured in the image is telling you EXACTLY what's wrong. In this chain `response.body().toString()` either `response` object is `null` (doubtful) or the call to `body()` is returning null. And so, you can call any method (in this case `toString()`) on a `null` reference.

Comment: Actually the error already says that it is not response to be null but the body

Comment: please clarify and write code

Answer (score 0):

You should move the log after the check for success. In general, unless you have a good reason to assume that a variable is not null it is better to check.
By the way you don't need to explicitly call the `toString` you can do something like `""+response.body()` and eventually you will get `null`.